# Invoking a type in Roslyn?

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

Is this possible with "Roslyn"?
Say that my `INameTypeSymbol` implements the interface `IFormatProvider`.
How do I invoke the `IFormatProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn is about inspecting & compiling code, not running it.

You need to compile the type (if it isn't already), load the assembly, then use Reflection to find the `System.Type` object for it and create an instance.

Comment: Not even via using `Activator.Create` and `Type.GetType`?

Comment: @AdamSpeight: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a way of doing it, since the Compiler already knows the type.

```
Dim FullyNamed = ArgTypes(0).ToDisplayString(
  New SymbolDisplayFormat(
    typeQualificationStyle:= SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.
    NameAndContainingTypesAndNamespaces ) )
Dim GottenType = Type.GetType(FullyNamed, False, True)
Dim Obj = GottenType.GetConstructors()(0).Invoke({Nothing})
```

I think it need to made it a function, which is applicable to any constructor.

```
Public Module Exts
  <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
  Public Function BuildMeOne( tt As Type) As Object
    Dim constructors = tt.GetConstructors()
    For Each xon In constructors
      Try
        dim obj=xon.Invoke( Enumerable.Repeat(Of Object)(Nothing, xon.GetParameters().count).ToArray)
        Return  obj
      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try
    Next
    Throw New Exception 
  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: `New Object()(xon.GetParameters().Count)`

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: This will only work for types in mscorlib, and not for generics.